# Can "point-down" be used as an adverb even we don't see it in dictionaries?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

I heard a native speaker say "**put the knife point-down into the basket**" when teaching people to put knives into a basket of a dish washer the right way.

And he said "**point-down**" is an adverb. But, I don't see that phrase in any dictionary.

I think most people would say "**put the knife into the basket with the point end down**" or
"**put the knife into the basket with the tip pointing down**" or something like that.

Can "**point-down**" be used as an adverb even we don't see it in dictionaries?

Also, **in which situations can we invent adverbs like that?**

Comment: Have you considered that "point-down" may be a compound adjective describing the knife?

Comment: It seems to refer both to the action of putting, and to the resulting state. Cook my eggs sunny side up. Place your cards face down.

Comment: When I read questions like this, I despair. Language exists for the benefit of its users. New phrases and new words are being created every day in every language across the world. There are all kinds of words that aren't in dictionaries -- slang words, for instance, take time to appear in dictionaries.